# Delete operator segfaults when the constructor throws an exception

Tags: c++, class, exception, delete-operator

Best to start with code to get an understanding of this

```
#include "Hello1.h"
#include "Hello2.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // Hello1 and Hello2 are derevied classes of Hello
    // And there constructor throws an exception
    Hello * h;

    try
    {
        if (argv[1][0]=='1')
            h = new Hello1;
        else
            h = new Hello2;
    }
    catch (std::exception ex) { /*print error*/ }

    delete h;
}
```

If `Hello1` and `Hello2` throws an exception, It **segfault**. However If I add

```
Hello h = NULL;
```

**It works!!!**

*Hello is a class with a constructor that throw's an exception*

All I can think of is that the exceptions in constructor's remove the object from memory! Why where who...Explain! Please.

Comment: What is `Hello`? A `typedef` for a pointer type or a type that can be constructed from its own pointer?

Comment: How can `h = new Hello1;` compile if `h` is not a pointer? Or did you mean `Hello* h`?

Comment: @Andy Prowl You are correct, sorry I am writing this from memory.

Comment: What is `Exception`? So you mean `std::exception`?

Comment: With `argv[1]=='1'` you're comparing a string with a character. And no, you can't do e.g. `argv[1]=="1"` either, though `std::string(argv[1])=="1"` will work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Writing from memory.

Comment: @Angel.King.47: Please don't "write from memory", please make sure that the code that you actually post compiles and generates the actual errors that you post. This saves everyone from following red herrings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However If I add `Hello h = NULL;` it works!!! Why where who...Explain! Please.

That is because `operator delete` does nothing when the pointer is `null`. It is expected to do nothing, that's standard behavior. Paragraph 3.7.4.2 of the C++11 Standard specifies:

> [...] The value of the
>   first argument supplied to a deallocation function may be a null pointer value; if so, and if the deallocation
>   function is one supplied in the standard library, **the call has no effect**. [...]

If it is not `null`, on the other hand, `operator delete` will try to delete the object pointed to by `hello`, and since the pointer is uninitialized (because construction threw and control was transferred to the exception handler before the assignment to `hello` happened), you get **undefined behavior**.

Per paragraph 5.3.5/2:

> [...] In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer
>   value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8)
>   representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). **If not, the behavior is undefined**. [...]

Comment: So I am right in thinking that any exceptions which where thrown in a constructor always determine the class to be undefined.

Comment: @Angel.King.47: I think you are trying to say the correct thing, but in an imprecise way. An object's lifetime begins when its initialization is complete. For class types, this is when the constructor returns. What follows from this is that if an exception is thrown in a constructor, the object never began to exist. If this is what you meant, then the answer is "Yes".

Comment: That is perfect, "if an exception is thrown in a constructor, the object never began to exist." is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Note: If you allocate other dynamic memory (via new) in the constructor before the exception is thrown it is your responsibility to clean it up before throwing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why where who...Explain! Please.

If `Hello`'s constructor throws `h` is never initialised - `delete` tries to read from that uninitialised variable and behaviour in undefined.

I recommend using a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` can throw exception if you try to delete something you should not delete. As others have pointed out, `delete` will not throw if you try to delete something set to `null`

`new` will, as far as I know, never throw unless you are out of memory.

So what happens is that `argv[1]` is not `'1'` and which means h is pointing to something unknown and this makes `delete` throw an exception